# Dynamic menu ruby on rails and partial

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, partial

i'm pretty new to rails and would like some help with implementing a dynamic menu using partials.

As of right now, my code is as follows:

the menu partial:

```
.three.columns
  %ul#nav

    %li{:class => @active_page=="about" ? "active_page" : ""}
      %a{:href => "../pages/about"} About
    %li{:class => @active_page=="careers" ? "active_page" : ""}
      %a{:href => "../pages/careers"} Careers
    %li{:class => @active_page=="contact" ? "active_page" : ""}
      %a{:href => "../pages/contact"} Contact
```

the view:

```
  html...
  = render :partial => 'shared/aboutmenu_nav'
  more html...
```

the pages helper:

```
def @active_page(c) 
controller.action_name == c 
end
```

Note: `active_page` is the class that I would like to pass to the `li` if the user is on the corresponding page. For example, if the user is on the Contact page, the active_page class would be passed to only the Contact li element.

I've tried several solutions including creating multiple CSS versions and passing a class on the `body` corresponding with the page? for example,

```
%body{:class => @page_name}
```

and then defining @page_name in the pages_helper as follows:

```
 def page_name
    @path.parameterize('_') unless @path.blank?
  end
```

Neither of these versions seem to work, as the former (@active_page) does not yield any results. Similarly, I was unable to assign a class on the body tag--when I checked the source code, the body tag did not have any classes.

I'd appreciate any help on how to implement a dynamic menu using partials. If there is a method I have not tried please feel free to inform me. I sincerely appreciate all of your help, and I'm very thankful for your time! Thank you!

Using Kanadada's solution. The page literally displays the following text where the styled menu should appear:

```
<li class="">
<a href="/pages/about">About</a>
</li>
<li class="active_page">
<a href="/pages/careers">Careers</a>
</li>
<li class="">
<a href="/pages/contact">Contact</a>
</li>
```

This code would be great if it was in the source code; however, the source does not seem to recognize it... instead the source code shows the following code:

```
 &lt;li class=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/pages/about&quot;&gt;About&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li class=&quot;active_page&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/pages/careers&quot;&gt;Careers&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li class=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/pages/contact&quot;&gt;Contact&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
```

I suspect that it might have something to do with the way `=top_menu` is interpreted in HAML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these methods to `helpers/appalication_helper.rb`

```
def active_menu?(path, path_right=request.path)
  (URI::parse(path).path == path_right) rescue false
end

def top_menu
  [
    "About",   "../pages/about", 
    "Careers", "../pages/careers", 
    "Contact", "../pages/contact"
  ].each_slice(2).map do |name, path|
    content_tag(:li, link_to(name, path), 
      :class => (active_menu?(path) ? "active_page" : ""))
  end.join('').html_safe
end
```

Now in your view:

```
.three.columns
  %ul#nav
    = top_menu
```

**Note:**

Use route helpers for path instead of hard coding them. Assuming you have a controller called `PagesController`, you can rewrite the `top_menu` method as follows:

```
def top_menu
  [
    "About",   about_pages_path, 
    "Careers", careers_pages_path, 
    "Contact", contact_pages_path
  ].each_slice(2).map do |name, path|
    content_tag(:li, link_to(name, path), 
      :class => (active_menu?(path) ? "active_page" : ""))
  end.join('').html_safe
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Kandada... The last set of code, does that do into the PagesController as in pages_controller.rb or a route file?

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: Thank you for the update, Kandada! However, when I use the suggestion above the section does not style... the page simply displays: <li class=""><a href="../pages/about">About</a></li><li class=""><a href="../pages/careers">Careers</a></li><li class=""><a href="../pages/contact">Contact</a></li>

Comment: Do not use the relative path. Use the 2nd approach I have suggested. I use this solution all the time. It works without any issues.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean relative path. I've tried your code, and it's not working. I did it exactly as listed above. Do i need to have something specific in the routes file? Also, I'm using HighVoltage for my static pages... could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Use `about_pages_path` instead of  `../pages/about`. If you still encounter errors, print the parameters to `active_menu?` method. Add the line `puts path, path_right` to the beginning of the method. The values will be printed in the server console. This should help you debug the issue.

Comment: i added the puts path, path_right and here is my output: ../pages/about
/pages/careers
../pages/careers
/pages/careers
../pages/contact
/pages/careers
also,should I include the code for application_helper.rb AND pagescontroller.rb or just one of them?

Comment: The issue is because you are using relative paths. Change the paths used in helper file from ../pages/about to /pages/about. Make this change for every menu item and it will work.

Comment: Kanadada... really thank you for all of your help. I'm so grateful! I have one issue... the page displays the code instead of the desired output... meaning that the page actually shows: <li class=""><a href="../pages/about">About</a></li><li class=""><a href="../pages/careers">Careers</a></li><li class=""><a href="../pages/contact">Contact</a></li> instead of links styled by the css. I hope that makes sense. Instead of being a menu styled by css it literally shows the entire code on the page, I've added what the source code shows in my post above... your help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have to add `html_safe` to the end of the method. In Rails 3 the html is escaped by default.

Comment: Kandada... Thank you so much! You did it! I'm very grateful for all of your help! It works perfectly. Thank you so much!!