# How do I apply an 'active' class to my navigation based on the current_page in a DRY way? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So in my `application.html.erb` I have my navigational structure that looks something like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
            <ul class="pills">
                    <% if current_page?(:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'index') %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Profile", vanity_path(:vname => current_user.username) %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Settings", settings_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path %></li>
                    <% elsif !current_page?(:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'index') %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Profile", vanity_path(:vname => current_user.username) %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Settings", settings_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path %></li>              
                    <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

However, what I would like to do, is once they are on any of the pages in the navigation, it applies a class `active` to the respective link.

So for instance, if the user is on `mydomain.com/johnbrown` which is the `Profile` link, the rails helper would look something like this:

`link_to "Profile", vanity_path(:vname => current_user.username), :class => "active"`.

But how do I do that in a programmatic way, so I am not duplicating content? i.e. how do I get that functionality for all the pages in my navigation and write it as DRY as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294181/dynamic-menu-ruby-on-rails-and-partial/7294580#7294580

Comment: Or this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705898/best-way-to-add-current-class-to-nav-in-rails-3

Answer (score 7):

This is a really great question. I've never really been happy with the solutions I've seen or come up with. Maybe we can get one together here.

Here is what I've tried in the past

I've made a helper that returns a hash with :class defined since I use HAML

```
def active_tab(path)
  request.path.match(/^#{path}/) ? { :class => 'active' } : {}
end
```

ex usage:

```
= link_to "Dashboard", dashboard_path, active_tab("#{dashboard_path}$")
```

Or an alternative along the same lines

```
def active_class(path)
  request.path =~ /#{path}/ ? 'active' : nil
end
```

ex usage:

```
= link_to 'Presentations', admin_presentations_path, :class => "#{active_class('presentations')}"
```

I would love to see some other suggestions on this.

Comment: Love this, but what would the `ERB` version look like? I can't see any differences between this version and ERB version...but given that you specified that you use HAML it is making me wonder.

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer for a bootstrap related navbar but you could easily use it with your nav.

[Answer taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481812/rails-dynamicly-adding-activate-class-to-bootstrap-nav-bar)

---

You can use helper for handle "current_page?", example a method :

```
module ApplicationHelper

 def is_active?(link_path)
  if current_page?(link_path)
    "active"
  else
    ""
  end
 end

end
```

example [bootstrap navbar](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar)

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, on view looks like

```
<li class="<%= is_active?(some_path) %>">
<%= link_to "name path", some_path %>
</li>
```

---

**For Haml**

Just simple looks like :

```
%ul.nav
  %li{class: current_page?(some_path) && 'active'}
    = link_to "About Us", some_path
```

Answer (score 1):

You may define a helper method in `application_helper.rb`

```
def create_link(text, path)
  class_name = current_page?(path) ? 'my_class' : ''

  content_tag(:li, class: class_name) do
    link_to text, path
  end
end
```

Now you can use like:

`create_link 'xyz', any_path` which would render as

```
<li class="my_class">
  <a href="/any">xyz</a>
</li>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just take the redundant parts out of the if else block?  Also take a look at 'link_to_unless'

```
 <div id="navigation">
        <ul class="pills">

                    <li><%= link_to_unless(current_page?(:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'index'), "Home", root_path %></li>

                   <li><%= link_to "Profile", vanity_path(:vname => current_user.username) %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Settings", settings_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path %></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
```

then I would add some jQuery to inject active class into the link that matches the window.location pattern.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Never knew about `link_to_unless`. Thanks for that. As for the jQuery, I would rather not use JS if I don't have to...i.e. if there is a Rails way, I would rather use that first.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a solution which was more like the link_to method and not pass an extra set of paramters.
You can do this by creating a method in `application_helper.rb` (or create a LinkHelper) which takes in the same 2 parameters as link_to:

```
def tab_to(title, path)
  link_to title, path, class: active_current_page(path)
end
```

Then create a private method to return the 'active' class:

```
def active_current_page(path)
  "active" if current_page?(path)
end
```

Full file as `link_helper.rb`:

```
module LinkHelper
  def tab_to(title, path)
    link_to title, path, class: active_current_page(path)
  end

  private

  def active_current_page(path)
    "active" if current_page?(path)
  end
end
```

This can then be called like this:

```
tab_to "Profile", vanity_path(:vname => current_user.username)
```