# Active class did not set to menu_item if url have '?' sign in twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I using gem https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/ and navbar helpers from them to build header.

For ex. i have a users link in my header. And if current url is '/users', users link sets active and highlighted correcrly. But if current url is '/users?top10=true', users link did not set active. Is there right behavior? Because html page for '/users' and /users?top10=true' is the same page with different content.

Is there bug or feature?

Comment: This is not a bug. Seems implementation issue. Can you show your layout where you are setting it active/non-active?

Comment: @RAJ active/non-active maked inside https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/#nav-links I just write 
`= menu_item 'Users', users_path`

 in my header.

Comment: It checks for proper match and not so reliable, solution can be manually setting active/non-active

Comment: @RAJ yes, manually setting active/non-active is solution. But i am interesting, Is there right helper's behavior?

Comment: I have added the explaination in the answer to avoid long list of comments

Comment: maybe, use `request.fullpath` method http://stackoverflow.com/a/17482101/1297435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap will only consider link as active if and only if path will match with `href`'s value. It don't have support for query strings yet. You can use following code options to make links active/non-active with custom code:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="<%= 'active' if controller_name == 'controller1' %>">
    <%= link_to "Link1", "/link1" %>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if controller_name == 'controller2' %>">
    <%= link_to "Link2", "/link2" %>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if controller_name == 'controller3' %>">
    <%= link_to "Link3", "/link3" %>
  </li>        
</ul>
```

Or you can use jQuery:

```
var url = window.location;

$('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```