# Spree active menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

**What do i want to achieve?**

I'm trying to add an active-menu (*highlight current page in the menu*) to my spree/ruby on rails application.

**What have I tried?**

After doing some research I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481812/dynamically-add-active-class-to-bootstrap-li-in-rails) question posted very helpful, but as you might have guessed the implementation of the solution I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481812/dynamically-add-active-class-to-bootstrap-li-in-rails) didn't get me the result I wanted.

The solution I found was adding the following code to the:

**The Code**

***application_helper.rb***

```
module ApplicationHelper

 def active_class(link_path)
  current_page?(link_path) ? "active" : ""
 end

end
```

***routes.rb***

```
   root 'spree/home#home'

   get '/specs', to: 'spree/home#specs'
   get '/about', to: 'spree/home#about'
   get '/purchase', to: 'spree/home#purchase'
   get '/support', to: 'spree/home#support'
```

***nav.html.erb***

```
<li class="<%= active_class(root_path) %>">
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
</li>

<li class="<%= active_class(purchase_path) %>">
<%= link_to "Purchase", purchase_path %>
</li>

<li>
<%= link_to "About", purchase_path %>
</li>

<li class="<%= active_class(specs_path) %>">
<%= link_to "Technical Details", specs_path %>
</li>

<li class="<%= active_class(support_path) %>">
<%= link_to
```

**The Error**

But now, no matter what page I go to I get the following error:

```
NameError in Spree::Home#purchase
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/mystore/app/views/spree/shared/_nav_bar.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined local variable or method `purchase_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f35a30c6b80>:0x007f35a3642a00>
Extracted source (around line #9):


</li>

<li class="<%= active_class(purchase_path) %>">
<%= link_to "Purchase", purchase_path %>
</li>
```

I've tried changing several variables, but to no avail

**My question is**:

How do i create an active menu in Spree (since it's the root of the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the reference below. I have used activated instead of active. you can style the activated class thereafter

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="link-section">
            <li class="<%= 'activated' if current_page?(root_path) %>">
                <a href="/">Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="<%= 'activated' if current_page?(new_user_registration_path) %>">
                <%= link_to("Register", new_user_registration_path) unless user_signed_in? %>
            </li>
            <li class="<%= 'activated' if current_page?(pricing_path) %>">
                <%= link_to("Pricing", pricing_path) %>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <% if current_user %>
                    <%= link_to("Store", shop_path(current_user.shop)) if current_user.shop.present? %>
                <% end %>
            </li>
            <li class="<%= 'activated' if current_page?(new_user_session_path) %>">
                <%= link_to("Login", new_user_session_path) unless user_signed_in? %>
            </li>
            <li class="<%= 'activated' if current_page?(dashboard_path) %>">
                <%= link_to("Dashboard", dashboard_path) if user_signed_in? %>
            </li>
            <li>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Rabin, Thank you for your response! I've tried applying you're method But I keep getting the same error. It seems spree doesn't recognize the code I added to the application_helper.rb